# SharePoint wehbooks on Modern Pages library

Tags: sharepoint-online, webhooks

I've a webhook on a Pages library which contains modern pages. While editing the modern page due to the auto-save feature, SP continuously sends notification to my endpoint. This results in too many messages in the storage queue which are then picked up by the webjob.
Is there a way to prevent so many messages going in to the queue ?
I can check if the item is published but that still involves querying sharepoint once per payload message sent by SharePoint.